# have an element in data set be passed as a column name

Tags: r

I need to get names from one data set that are the names columns in a second data set, but when I try to it say the second data set is NULL.
 For example wanting to grad "colors" form the var_list, and applied it to the full data set with the column name "color".I have made it so that the values in the var_list data set have the same names as column names in the full data set.

```
z <- var_list$var[1] 

print(z)

colors

full_data$z 

Null
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `names` inside `[]`:

```
var_list <- data.frame(var="colors",other="any",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
full_data <- data.frame(colors=1:4, o=1:2)
z <- var_list$var[1]

full_data[names(full_data)==z]
```